# Probability question concerning number of leaders in a competition

Tags: probability, puzzle

We have 30 competitors and they are throwing a hammer. Let's assume they have equal skill. Let's assume competitors cannot have equal throws. Each one throws only once. If result of a competitor is better then result of previous competitors then he becomes a temporary leader. What is expected value of a numbers of leaders in this competition?

I have issues with expressing this question in framework of probability, I see that the answer is greater than $\frac{3}{2}$ because first competitor always becomes a leader and the second one has $50\%$ chance to become one, but I get confused after that.

Comment: *Hint:* Linearity of expectation is particularly powerful here.

Comment: How can I use linearity of expectation here, what could be a useful choice of random variables? $X_i =$ i-th was a leader?

Comment: Yes, precisely.  Letting $X_i=1$ if $i$ was a temporary leader and $0$ otherwise, the total number of temporary leaders is the sum of the $X_i$'s.  Then its just a matter of applying simple arguments.  To simplify things at the end, you might choose to describe using [Harmonic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: If I understand correctly the answer is about 4, because expected value of $X_i$ is $1/i$, thank you.